# Is there English version (published) of Grothendieck's EGA and SGA?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

My interest in the applications of algebraic geometry led me to study its basics.  I am interested in reading Grothendieck's EGA and SGA, which are believed to be the bible of the algebraic geometer.  I would like to start taking looks at them.

What I discovered is that both books are written in French, and I could not really discover any translated editions in English.  Perhaps it has to do with my lack of searching capabilities.  By any chance, do you know English, published editions for both EGA and SGA?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/31647/is-an-english-translation-of-grothendiecks-ega-available

Comment: [An expert account](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/12253/11619). Mind you, I, too, found this irritating when I was younger and felt the need to learn AG. I never really did and tried to manage with whatever I could pick up from other sources.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in the comments, see [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/338966/73622) on MathOverflow — there is an [open-source community translation project for EGA](https://github.com/ryankeleti/ega) that has made quite a bit of progress (EGA 1 is now completely finished, for example), and is still semi-regularly active :-)

**Update:** there is also an [SGA project](https://github.com/thosgood/sga), but I have no real intentions to work on this consistently before finishing at least the entirety of [the FGA](https://github.com/thosgood/fga) and EGA II. It is, however, obviously open for contributions by anybody! And I haphazardly translate a few sections once in a blue moon when I need them for my own research.